# How should I prevent second page of site's front page from being indexed?

Tags: nodes

My website's second page has the URL http://example.com/node?page=1

I've got the marinelli theme installed.

For SEO purposes, what should be done for the second page node?page=1 of blog listings? Should I disallow it from robots.txt or do something else?

Comment: Is it not /node/2 ? Usually for SEO purpose nothing much needs to be done from our side(beyond title & article content,keywords) and Google is very smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: @AgA: Google is very smart, but we need to take care as well! I believe pages that aren't terribly important to appear in search results need to be blocked out for the lack of freshness.

Comment: I think it's a waste exercise. Today's CMS generates tons of waste and duplicate url's. But still everything is fine with Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `view?page=1` will almost always be the same as `view`, you should add these lines to your robots.txt

```
Disallow: /*sort=
Disallow: /*order=
Disallow: /*page=1
```

More at: http://larsolesen.dk/content/struggling-duplicate-content-drupal-7